# Android Spinner: Get Value from Selection

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I am using a spinner populating with an xml file:

```
<string-array name="Spinner Items">
<item>Item 1: 2.0 - 4.0</item>
<item>Item 2: 1.0 - 3.0</item>
```

Is it possible to set a name value pair like this:

```
<string-array name="Spinner Items">
<item name="Item 1: 2.0 - 4.0" value="2"></item>
<item name="Item 2: 1.0 - 3.0" value="1.5"></item>
```

So that I can populate the spinner with the name and then when an item is selected it returns the value of that specific item? I figure it must be easier to do all this in the xml file as opposed to have to write if statement for each item when the spinner is changed. Of course the real xml file is much longer than this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to implement a custom adapter-class.

Comment: I'm ok with that...you don't by chance have a link or something to an example do you? Sorry, i'm a little lost here and google isn't helping me find my answer.

Comment: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/10/spinner-and-its-data-behind.html - number 1. comment on that page.

Comment: Looks good. I guess I can't do this in an xml file, but that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did it wrong way, but it works.
My Spinner(spinnerSex) contains Male/Female choice:

```
<string-array name="spinnerSex">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>
</string-array>
```

java code:

```
Object objSelectedItem = spinnerSex.getSelectedItem();
String strSelectedItem = String.valueOf(objSelectedItem);
String[] arrvals = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnerValues);
boolean isMale = (strSelectedItem.equals(arrvals[0]));
```